# Find $a$ in terms of $b$ if $b = ({a \over 5})^{a+1}$

Tags: functions, logarithms, inverse-function

Find $a$ in terms of $b$ if $b = ({a \over 5})^{a+1}$.

Firstly,

> is this possible (within elementary functions)

and secondly,

> if so, how is it done?

also, can someone help me tag this, I don't really now which tags to use.

Comment: Do you consider the Lambert W function "elementary"? If not, the answer is probably no. (If "yes", then it may be possible but I don't have the time to work it out now so I'm not certain).

Comment: @Deepak Go for it, I'm making no progress with roots, logarithms or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with Lambert function, there is no explicit solution because of the $+1$ in the exponent.

I guess that numerical methods would be needed. For starting, let $a=5c$ and consider that you look for the zero's of function
$$f(c)=c^{5 c+1}-b$$ or, much better
$$g(c)=(5c+1)\log(c)-\log(b)$$ Computing the derivatives
$$g'(c)=\frac{1}{c}+5 \log (c)+5\qquad \text{and} \qquad g''(c)=\frac{5 c-1}{c^2}$$

The first derivative cancels at
$$c_*=-\frac{1}{5 W\left(-\frac{e}{5}\right)}$$ which is not a real. So, the derivative is positive and $g(c)$ is an increasing function with a positive second derivative as soon as $c > \frac 15$.

Newton method will not face any problem; the only thing, foor saving iterations, is that we need a "reasonable" guess $c_0$ to start with.

Ignoring the $+1$, we could that start using
$$c_0=\frac{\log (b)}{5 W\left(\frac{\log (b)}{5}\right)}$$ which will be an overestimate of the solution since $g(c_0) > 0$.

Let us try for $b=123456789$. The iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & c_n \\
 0 & 3.201940306 \\
 1 & 3.097390221 \\
 2 & 3.096653690 \\
 3 & 3.096653653
\end{array}
\right)$$ then $a=15.483268263$.

Trying for $b=123456789\times 10^{100}$, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & c_n \\
 0 & 17.41954887 \\
 1 & 17.27183432 \\
 2 & 17.27167350
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

As I wrote, if you want to save iterations, a "good" estimate $c_0$ is required.

Let me take the second case with $c_0=1$. The method  will provide the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & c_n \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 42.48165184 \\
 2 & 19.29197737 \\
 3 & 17.29900434 \\
 4 & 17.27167903 \\
 5 & 17.27167350
\end{array}
\right)$$ All of that can very easily be done with Excel (or whatever).

**Update**

Assuming that you would accept the proposed expression for $c_0$ you could have a better *approximation* using the simple $[1,1]$ Padé approximant of $g(c)$ built at $c=c_0$. This would give
$$c_1=c_0+\frac{2 \,g(c_0)\, g'(c_0)}{g(c_0)\, g''(c_0)-2\, g'(c_0)^2}$$

For the worked examples, this would give $c_1=3.09667$ and $c_1=17.2717$. This does not seem to be too bad. Be sure that we can still improve it using $[1,n]$ Padé approximant.

Comment: Is there any way it could be solved with other non-elementary functions (other than just its own inverse function)?

Comment: @L.McDonald. SInce even Lambert function cannot be used, you are restricted to numercal method. Newton is very simple to use. The only problem is the initial guess. If the search for *Lambert function Wikipedia*, you will find series easy to use for an estimate.